# PHP MySQL scoreboard with link to profile page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with a scoreboard that gets results from a view in the wp database and I ve set up the board on a custom page template.My trouble is to link the players in the scoreboard to a new page with players stats etc. I want to be able to click the player name in the scoreboard and then get to a page with stats for that player.

Here is the relevant code that displays the scoreboard:

```
<?php //Table with SQL Query
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
mysql_select_db('worldsbestblog');

$query = "SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt LIMIT 0,20"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Loop through results
    echo    "<tr><td>" . $row['Dato'] . "</td>
            <td>
                <a href=\"fasan.php?id=". $row["spillerid"]."\">" . $row['Navn'] . "</a>
            </td>
            <td>" . $row['hull1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull2'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull3'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull4'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull5'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull6'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull7'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull8'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull9'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull10'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull11'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull12'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull13'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull14'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull15'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull16'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull17'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull18'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['Sammenlagt'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Par'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['Poeng'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a column name
            }
?>
```

I've seen countless similar questions where SESSIONS, $_POST and $_GET has been used though I havent been able to either understand or see how/if thats what's missing in order to make it work. 
As it is now i get a URL showing the userid of player, but when clicked, wordpress cant find that page.

---

[edit]
OK I have done some editing and found an answer to my question. Unsure how to go about here on stackoverflow (direct me if I should do this elsewhere), but I want to show you what did the job so that the next guy will find this post with an explanation.

So here is the current code and thanks to @Cal Evans and @Hamed Momeni for helpful guidance:

Scoreboard goes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through     results
echo    "<tr><td>" . $row['Dato'] . "</td>
    <td>
        <a href=\"/wordpress/teststats?id=". $row["spillerid"]."\">" . $row['Navn'] . "</a>
    </td>
    <td>" . $row['hull1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull2'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull3'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull4'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull5'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull6'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull7'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull8'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull9'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull10'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull11'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull12'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull13'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull14'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull15'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull16'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['hull17'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull18'] . 
    "</td><td>" . $row['Sammenlagt'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Par'] .
    "</td><td>" . $row['Poeng'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a column name
}
?>
```

`.../wordpress/teststats` is a new page with a custom page template with the  following code:

```
<?php

$spid = (int) filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$spillerquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt WHERE spillerid='$spid'") or die ("Somthing went wrong!!"); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($spillerquery) < 1){
        die ("Couldnt find that player");
    }
    $navnequery = mysql_query("SELECT Navn FROM Sammenlagt WHERE spillerid='$spid'") or die ("Player does not exist");
    $spillernavn = mysql_result($navnequery,MYSQL_BOTH);
?>

<h2>Her er <?php echo "$spillernavn"; ?> sine resultater</h2>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($spillerquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo    "<tr><td>" . $row['Dato'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull2'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull3'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull4'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull5'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull6'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull7'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull8'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull9'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull10'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull11'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull12'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull13'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull14'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull15'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull16'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['hull17'] . "</td><td>" . $row['hull18'] . 
            "</td><td>" . $row['Sammenlagt'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Par'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['Poeng'] . "</td></tr>";
    }   

?>
```

Comment: What is the url that you are trying to get to in relation to the calling page?  If you are getting a "wordpress cant find that page" problem, I think that your problem is less mysql related and more link path related.

Comment: I can just tell by your `$row` output that your database structure needs some work.  How can you keep track of all of those hulls?

Comment: @zero298 - url is mypage.org/wordpress/test/fasan.php?id=12  where "12" is the playerid from the database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure zero just gave the right answer. But, you should be considering rewriting a bit. the mysql_ extension is deprecated. You should look into PDO, or at the very least mysqli_, since it's really similar in structure.

Comment: @Devon - hulls are score pr hole. It's a scoreboard for golf.

Comment: @iontomet Ah, that makes a little bit more sense.  A golf scorecard.

Comment: @iontomet.  If I were you, I would have a separate table for the scores.  Something like player, hole, score, date (or round).  This would allow you to have more separation for the scores and allow you to perform math functions with ease such as a sum per round, average, etc.

Comment: Your URL in your code links to `fasan.php` as relative path, not `/wordpress/test/fasan.php` as absolute path.  Unless this page exists at `/wordpress/test/*` the URL will not work.

Comment: BTW, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Devon. The query as it is now, gets its data from a VIEW where relevant data already is grouped and ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php 
//Table with SQL Query

$player_id = (int) filter_input(INPUT_GET,'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);
mysql_select_db('worldsbestblog');

$query = "SELECT * FROM Sammenlagt where player_id = {$player_id} LIMIT 0,20"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Although, I do agree [with @Hamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075297/8053001) that you should be using `$wpdb` instead of creating your own connection. This is assuming that your table is in the same database as your WordPress tables.

Comment: As the code is now, the $query is used for filling the scoreboard. Would you suggest I setup a second variable to query the player_id then used that for the `fasan.php?id=....`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, misunderstood the question. Create a link on the Player's name that has ?id=NNN where NNN is the player's ID. Then in that page's template, add the code I put in there. Adjust the table name to pull from the players table.

Comment: That worked! Added that $player_id variable to the profile page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using Wordpress I suggest you use the provided `$wpdb` object for your Database needs.
The other suggestion is when using Wordpress you need to use template files for creating different pages. You can [create different page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) for various pages inside Wordpress. That way you can use the Wordpress rerouting engine for its powerful and easy features.

For example imagine you want to create a page for player stats. First create a file with the name `tpl-player_stats.php` inside your theme dir with the following header:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Player Stats Page
*/
```

And then inside Wordpress dashboar create a page and assign the above template to it. After that you can go to your page by going to `http://example.com/your_page_slug/?id=player_id`.
Generally this is how it's done with Wordpress. So I suggest you dig into that.

Comment: Yes, I am using WP and its database with custom page template.. sorry for not being that detailed in the first place (original post updated). I studied some tuts on using $wpdb but i struggled to get it working so I found that the regular connection method would do. Will look into that and also the rerouting engine you mention, thank you